Firebase Cloud Function returns "DEADLINE EXCEEDED" in Flutter app
I've built a cloud function in JavaScript (node: 18) to use the Gemini AI in my Flutter app. This function generates a list of workouts that may be long enough to throw a "DEADLINE EXCEEDED" error. However, the function worked successfully (status code: 200), so the problem should be in the length of the response. In fact, the error is thrown by the bloc function from which I call the cloud function.
Here are the debug console, the could function, the bloc function and the function log.
Debug console:
[firebase_functions/deadline-exceeded] DEADLINE EXCEEDED

#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:648:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:22:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:49:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      new GenerateWorkoutBloc.<anonymous closure> (package:energi/logic/blocs/generate_workout/generate_workout_bloc.dart:24:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      Bloc.on.<anonymous closure>.handleEvent (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:229:13)
<asynchronous suspension>

Cloud function:
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { GoogleGenerativeAI } = require("@google/generative-ai");
const { prompt } = require("./prompt.cjs");

const apiKey = "key";
const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(apiKey);

const generationConfig = {
  temperature: 0,
  topP: 0.95,
  topK: 64,
  maxOutputTokens: 8192,
  responseMimeType: "application/json",
  responseSchema: {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      routine: {
        type: "object",
        properties: {
          workoutList: {
            type: "array",
            items: {
              type: "object",
              properties: {
                title: {
                  type: "string"
                },
                exerciseList: {
                  type: "array",
                  items: {
                    type: "object",
                    properties: {
                      exercise: {
                        type: "object",
                        properties: {
                          title: {
                            type: "string"
                          },
                          setList: {
                            type: "array",
                            items: {
                              type: "string"
                            }
                          },
                          timer: {
                            type: "integer"
                          },
                          id: {
                            type: "string"
                          }
                        },
                        required: [
                          "title",
                          "setList",
                          "timer",
                          "id"
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    required: [
                      "exercise"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              required: [
                "title",
                "exerciseList"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        required: [
          "workoutList"
        ]
      }
    },
    required: [
      "routine"
    ]
  },
};

const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({
  model: "gemini-1.5-flash",
  generationConfig: generationConfig,
});

const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 300,
}


exports.generateWorkout = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const content = await model.generateContent(prompt);
    const response = content.response.text();
    res.status(200).send({ data: response });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

Bloc function:
on<Generate>((event, emit) async {
      emit(GenerateWorkoutInProgress());
      try {
        HttpsCallable callable =
            FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('generateWorkout');
        final response = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "routine": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "workoutList": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "title": {"type": "string"},
                      "exerciseList": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                          "type": "object",
                          "properties": {
                            "exercise": {
                              "type": "object",
                              "properties": {
                                "title": {"type": "string"},
                                "setList": {
                                  "type": "array",
                                  "items": {"type": "string"}
                                },
                                "timer": {"type": "integer"},
                                "id": {"type": "string"}
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        });
        final workouts = await fromAiData(
            json.decode(response.data) as Map<String, dynamic>);
        emit(GenerateWorkoutSuccess(workouts: workouts));
      } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
        emit(GenerateWorkoutError());
        print(error.toString());
      } catch (error) {
        emit(GenerateWorkoutError());
        print(error.toString());
      }
    });


UPDATE: Here is the definition of the deadline exceeded error provided by the Firebase documentation:
deadline-exceeded: Deadline expired before operation could complete. For operations that change the state of the system, this error may be returned even if the operation has completed successfully. For example, a successful response from a server could have been delayed long enough for the deadline to expire.

You're mixing up HTTP and callable type functions.  Your app code is trying to invoke a callable function using the provided SDK, but your backend function is implemented as an HTTP onRequest function.  This is not going to work as you'd expect.  Callable type functions use a special protocol that is not implemented by onRequest.
If you want to use a callable type function, you need to follow the documentation and use an onCall function on the backend (and not onRequest).  Or, if you want to use a normal HTTP onRequest type function, you should invoke it with a normal HTTP client library (not the Firebase SDK).

I tried switching to a onCall function as you suggested, but the same error is thrown
